# Possible create named tuple type using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, tuples, namedtuple

I can create a normal tuple type with `Tuple.Create` or `typeof(Tuple<,>).MakeGenericType` etc, but how can I make a named tuple? With other property names than `Item1`, `Item2` etc, using reflection in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, because named tuples are largely just syntatic sugar.

If you consider this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var abc = Get();
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}: {1}", abc.name, abc.age));  
}

private (string name, int age) Get()
{
    return ("John", 30);
}
```

and then look at the decompiled code (I used JetBrains' dotPeek):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ValueTuple<string, int> valueTuple = this.Get();
  int num = (int) MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (object) valueTuple.Item1, (object) (int) valueTuple.Item2));
}

[return: TupleElementNames(new string[] {"name", "age"})]
private ValueTuple<string, int> Get()
{
  return new ValueTuple<string, int>("John", 30);
}
```

You can see that, even though the MessageBox code uses the names, it's actually converted to `.Item1` and `.Item2` when it's compiled. Therefore, you should just use the ValueType constructor.